# How to extend flood control in a custom module?

Tags: 7, security, users

I would like to use Drupal's flood control capability in another module. I have a resource I'm protecting with a password.

Can I simply call [flood_register_event()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/flood_register_event/7) and otherwise use the variables as used in the code for [user_login_final_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_final_validate/7)?

Am I on the right track at all, or how do I use flood control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do 3 things when you validate your password entry form:

1. Use [flood_is_allowed()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/flood_is_allowed/7) to check that the user hasn't already breached their flood limit and set a form error with [form_set_error()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) if they have.
2. Use [flood_register_event()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/flood_register_event/7) to log failed attempts on incorrect password errors.
3. Use [flood_clear_event()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/flood_clear_event/7) when the user enters the correct password.

You can also decide whether to do it based on uid, ipaddress, both of those, or something else entirely.

You can see the example of the user module in [user_login_authenticate_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate/7) and [user_login_final_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_final_validate/7). That example may or may not be more complex than you need in your specific case.